# ThorsSQL Lib: Part 3: Layer 5 HandShake

Tags: c++, c++11, mysql, c++14, library

Have a working version of MySQL implementation of ThorsSQL library done.

If you want to check it out you can find the whole thing on [github ThorsSQL](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL/tree/ef508c463aded45dd1ce0605a907f41f589b76b4).

This is a follow on to previous code Reviews:
[Part 3: Layer 5 Req/Resp](/q/158220/507)
[Part 3: Layer 4](/q/158139/507)
[Part 3: Layer 3](/q/158113/507)
[Part 3: Layer 2](/q/158052/507)
[Part 3: Layer 1](/q/158007/507)
[Part 2](/q/94901/507)
[Part 1](/q/94899/507)

The [documentation for these classes is here](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL/tree/ef508c463aded45dd1ce0605a907f41f589b76b4/src/MySQL/ReadMe.md):

### Part 3 (Layer 5): The HandShake Resp and Reply

When you first connect to a MySQL server; the first action of the server is to send you a `HandShake` package.

The client should check the `HandShake` package make sure it knows the protocol suggested by the server. Then send a `HandShakeResponse` message to the server. If everything goes well the server will send back `OK` response.

If we look at the code I posted for Layer 4 you may have spotted this happening when the `Connection` object was initially created (added below for reference).

```
Connection::Connection(
                    std::string const& username,
                    std::string const& password,
                    std::string const& database,
                    std::map<std::string, std::string> const& options,
                    ConectReader& pr,
                    ConectWriter& pw)
    : packageReader(pr)
    , packageWriter(pw)
{
    std::unique_ptr<RespPackage> initPack = recvMessage(
                                                {{0x0A, [](int firstByte, ConectReader& reader
                                                          )
                                                        {return new RespPackageHandShake(firstByte, reader);}
                                                 }
                                                });
    std::unique_ptr<RespPackageHandShake> handshake = downcastUniquePtr<RespPackageHandShake>(std::move(initPack));
    packageReader.initFromHandshake(handshake->getCapabilities(), handshake->getCharset());
    packageWriter.initFromHandshake(handshake->getCapabilities(), handshake->getCharset());

    RequPackageHandShakeResponse    handshakeresp(username, password, options, database, *handshake);
    std::unique_ptr<RespPackage>    ok = sendHandshakeMessage<RespPackage>(handshakeresp,
        {{0xFE, [](int firstByte, ConectReader& reader)
                {return new RespPackageAuthSwitchRequest(firstByte, reader);}
         }
        });

    if (!ok)
    {
        throw std::domain_error("Connection::Connection: Handshake failed: Unexpected Package");
    }
    if (!(ok->isOK()))
    {
        throw std::domain_error(errorMsg("Connection::Connection: Handshake failed: Got: ", (*ok)));
    }
}
```

So the first object we receive above (with the call `recvMessage()`) from the server is `RespPackageHandShake`.

The client then starts a Requ/Resp cycle (with the call `sendHandshakeMessage()`) sending a `RequPackageHandShakeResponse` object back to the server.

Note: Normally we use the `sendMessageGetResponse()` to send messages to the server, the difference between this and `sendHandshakeMessage()` is that former resets the package number count (at layer 2) to zero before starting the interaction with server since we are continuing a discussion started by the server we don't want to reset this count to zero (this is the one special case).

If everything goes well then we should get `RespPackageOK` returned. **BUT** the server may want to change authentication protocol in which case it will return a `RespPackageAuthSwitchRequest` asking the client for better authentication.

Currently this client does not support that and will throw an exception (A fun task for somebody that want to try :-) )

You will notice that the `HandShakeResponse` object contains all the work for encrypting the password for transport to the server using some random key data provided by the initial `HandShake`.

### RespPackageHandShake.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_PACKAGE_RESP_HAND_SHAKE_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_PACKAGE_RESP_HAND_SHAKE_H

#include "RespPackage.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iomanip>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace MySQL
    {

class ConectReader;

class RespPackageHandShake: public RespPackage
{
    std::string     serverVersion;
    long            connectionID;
    std::string     authPluginData;
    long            check;
    //--
    long            statusFlag;
    long            authPluginLength;
    std::string     reserved;
    std::string     authPluginName;
    bool            isV9;
    long            capabilities;
    char            charset;

    public:
        RespPackageHandShake(int firstByte, ConectReader& reader);
        virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream& s)    const;
        long                getCapabilities()           const   {return capabilities;}
        long                getCharset()                const   {return charset;}
        std::string const&  getAuthPluginName()         const   {return authPluginName;}
        std::string const&  getAuthPluginData()         const   {return authPluginData;}
};

inline std::ostream& RespPackageHandShake::print(std::ostream& s) const
{
    std::stringstream reservedDecoded;
    for (char x: reserved)
    {
        reservedDecoded << "0x" << std::hex << static_cast<int>(x) << " ";
    }
    std::stringstream authPluginDataDecoded;
    for (char x: authPluginData)
    {
        authPluginDataDecoded << "0x" << std::hex << static_cast<int>(x) << " ";
    }

    return s << "RespPackageHandShake: "
             << "serverVersion(" << serverVersion << ") "
             << "connectionID(" << connectionID << ") "
             << "authPluginData(" << authPluginDataDecoded.str() << ") "
             << "check(" << check << ") "
             << "statusFlag( 0x" << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << statusFlag << ") "
             << "authPluginLength(" << authPluginLength << ") "
             << "reserved("  << reservedDecoded.str() << ") "
             << "authPluginName(" << authPluginName << ") "
             << "capabilities(" << capabilities << ") "
             << "isV9(" << isV9 << ") "
             << std::dec;
}

    }
}

#endif
```

### RespPackageHandShake.cpp

```
#include "ThorMySQL.h"
#include "ConectReader.h"
#include "RespPackageHandShake.h"
#include <cassert>

using namespace ThorsAnvil::MySQL;

RespPackageHandShake::RespPackageHandShake(int firstbyte, ConectReader& reader)
    : RespPackage(reader, "HandShake")
    , serverVersion(reader.nulTerminatedString())
    , connectionID(reader.fixedLengthInteger<4>())
    , authPluginData(reader.fixedLengthString(8))
    , check(0)
    , statusFlag(0)
    , authPluginLength(0)
    , isV9(false)
    , capabilities(0)
{
    // https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::HandshakeV10
    assert(firstbyte = 0x0A);

    if (reader.isEmpty())
    {
        isV9    = true;
        return;
    }
    check           = reader.fixedLengthInteger<1>();
    capabilities    = reader.fixedLengthInteger<2>();

    if (reader.isEmpty())
    {
        return;
    }

    charset         = reader.fixedLengthInteger<1>();
    statusFlag      = reader.fixedLengthInteger<2>();
    long cap2       = reader.fixedLengthInteger<2>();
    authPluginLength= 0;

    capabilities    = capabilities | (cap2 << 16);

    if (capabilities & CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH)
    {
        authPluginLength= reader.fixedLengthInteger<1>();
    }
    else
    {
        int fill = reader.fixedLengthInteger<1>();
        assert(fill == 0);
    }

    reserved        = reader.fixedLengthString(10);
    std::string authPluginData2;
    if (capabilities & CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION)
    {
        authPluginData2 = reader.variableLengthString(std::max(13L, authPluginLength - 8L));
    }
    if (capabilities & CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH)
    {
        authPluginName  = reader.nulTerminatedString();
    }

    // Because of the way 13L is the min size for authPluginData2 data
    // This may exceed the actual size of the auth data. So after concatenating the
    // data make sure we only use the required length `authPluginLength`. This means
    // removing the extra terminating '\0' character.
    // see: mysql-5.7/sql/auth/sql_authentication.cc 538
    // the 13th byte is "\0 byte, terminating the second part of a scramble"
    authPluginData  = (authPluginData + authPluginData2).substr(0, authPluginLength-1);
}
```

### RequPackageHandShakeResp.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_PACKAGE_REQU_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_PACKAGE_REQU_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE_H

#include "RequPackage.h"
#include "ThorSQL/SQLUtil.h"
#include <string>
#include <ostream>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace MySQL
    {

using Options=SQL::Options;
class RespPackageHandShake;
class ConectWriter;

class RequPackageHandShakeResponse: public RequPackage
{
    std::string const& username;
    std::string        authResponse;
    Options const&     options;
    std::string const& database;
    std::string const& authPluginName;
    long               capabilities;

    public:
        RequPackageHandShakeResponse(std::string const& username,
                                 std::string const& password,
                                 Options const& options,
                                 std::string const& database,
                                 RespPackageHandShake const& handshake);

        virtual  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& s)   const override;
        virtual  void build(ConectWriter& writer)       const override;
};

    }
}

#endif
```

### RequPackageHandShakeResp.cpp

```
#include "ThorMySQL.h"
#include "RequPackageHandShakeResp.h"
#include "RespPackageHandShake.h"
#include "ThorCryptWrapper.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::MySQL;

RequPackageHandShakeResponse::RequPackageHandShakeResponse(std::string const& username,
                                                           std::string const& password,
                                                           Options const&     options,
                                                           std::string const& database,
                                                           RespPackageHandShake const& handshake)
    : RequPackage("RequPackageHandShakeResponse", "HandShake-Response")
    , username(username)
    , options(options)
    , database(database)
    , authPluginName(handshake.getAuthPluginName())
    , capabilities(handshake.getCapabilities())
{
    if (authPluginName == "mysql_old_password")
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                errorMsg("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::HandshakeResponsePackage::HandshakeResponsePackage: ",
                         "mysql_old_password: not supported"
              ));
    }
    else if (authPluginName == "mysql_clear_password")
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                errorMsg("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::HandshakeResponsePackage::HandshakeResponsePackage: ",
                         "mysql_clear_password: not supported"
              ));
    }
    else if (authPluginName == "authentication_windows_client")
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                errorMsg("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::HandshakeResponsePackage::HandshakeResponsePackage: ",
                         "authentication_windows_client: not supported"
              ));
    }
    else if (authPluginName == "sha256_password")
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                errorMsg("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::HandshakeResponsePackage::HandshakeResponsePackage: ",
                         "sha256_password: not supported"
              ));
    }
    else if (authPluginName == "mysql_native_password")
    {
        // Requires CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION
        // SHA1( password ) XOR SHA1( "20-bytes random data from server" <concat> SHA1( SHA1( password ) ) )
        ThorSHADigestStore  stage1;
        thorSHA1(stage1, password);


        ThorSHADigestStore  stage2;
        thorSHA1(stage2, stage1);

        std::string extendedAuth = handshake.getAuthPluginData() + std::string(stage2, stage2 + SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
        ThorSHADigestStore  extendedHash;
        thorSHA1(extendedHash, extendedAuth);

        for (int loop=0;loop < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH;++loop)
        {
            extendedHash[loop] = extendedHash[loop] ^ stage1[loop];
        }
        authResponse    = std::string(extendedHash, extendedHash + SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                errorMsg("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::HandshakeResponsePackage::HandshakeResponsePackage: ",
                         "UNKNOWN authentication method(", authPluginName, "): not supported"
              ));
    }
}

void RequPackageHandShakeResponse::build(ConectWriter& writer) const
{
    // These capabilities mirror the `mysql` tool.
    // We will leave this for now but it may change
    // as the understanding of the system updates.
    unsigned long cap  = CLIENT_SET_CLIENT | CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH_LENENC_CLIENT_DATA | CLIENT_CONNECT_ATTRS
                 | CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH | CLIENT_PS_MULTI_RESULTS | CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS | CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS
                 | CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION | CLIENT_TRANSACTIONS
                 | CLIENT_INTERACTIVE | CLIENT_PROTOCOL_41
                 | CLIENT_LOCAL_FILES
                 | CLIENT_CONNECT_WITH_DB | CLIENT_LONG_FLAG | CLIENT_LONG_PASSWORD;

    // https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::HandshakeResponse41
    // Turn off flags not supported by the server
    unsigned long localCap = capabilities & cap;
    writer.writeFixedLengthInteger<4>(localCap);

    long maxPacketSize   = 0x01000000;
    writer.writeFixedLengthInteger<4>(maxPacketSize);

    unsigned char charset = 0x21;
    writer.writeFixedLengthInteger<1>(charset);

    std::string reserved(23, '\0');
    writer.writeFixedLengthString(reserved, 23);

    writer.writeNullTerminatedString(username);

    if (localCap & CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH_LENENC_CLIENT_DATA)
    {
        writer.writeLengthEncodedInteger(authResponse.size());
        writer.writeFixedLengthString(authResponse, authResponse.size());
    }
    else if (localCap & CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION)
    {
        char val = authResponse.size();
        writer.writeFixedLengthInteger<1>(val);
        writer.writeFixedLengthString(authResponse, authResponse.size());
    }
    else
    {
        writer.writeNullTerminatedString(authResponse);
    }

    if (localCap & CLIENT_CONNECT_WITH_DB)
    {
        writer.writeNullTerminatedString(database);
    }

    if (localCap & CLIENT_PLUGIN_AUTH)
    {
        writer.writeNullTerminatedString(authPluginName);
    }

    // TODO Add Key Values
    // For now empty the options
    if (localCap & CLIENT_CONNECT_ATTRS)
    {
        std::size_t size = 0;
        for (auto const& loop: options)
        {
            size    += loop.first.size() + loop.second.size();
        }
        writer.writeLengthEncodedInteger(size);
        for (auto const& loop: options)
        {
            writer.writeLengthEncodedString(loop.first);
            writer.writeLengthEncodedString(loop.second);
        }
    }
}

std::ostream& RequPackageHandShakeResponse::print(std::ostream& s) const
{
    std::stringstream authRespDecoded;
    for (char x: authResponse)
    {   authRespDecoded << "0x" << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(x)) << " ";
    }
    std::stringstream keyValDecoded;
    for (auto const& val: options)
    {   keyValDecoded << "KV(" << val.first << " => " << val.second << ") ";
    }

    return s << "HandshakeResponsePackage: "
             << "username(" << username << ") "
             << "authResponse(" << authRespDecoded.str() << ") "
             << "options(" << keyValDecoded.str() << ") "
             << "database(" << database << ") "
             << "authPluginName(" << authPluginName << ") "
             << "capabilities(" << capabilities << ") ";
}
```

### RespPackageAuthSwitchRequest.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_PACKAGE_RESP_EOF_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_PACKAGE_RESP_EOF_H

#include "RespPackage.h"
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cassert>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace MySQL
    {

class ConectReader;

class RespPackageAuthSwitchRequest: public RespPackage
{
    public:
        std::string pluginName;
        std::string pluginData;

        RespPackageAuthSwitchRequest(int firstByte, ConectReader& reader)
            : RespPackage(reader, "AuthSwitchRequest")
            , pluginName(reader.nulTerminatedString())
            , pluginData(reader.restOfPacketString())
        {
            // https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase-packets.html#packet-Protocol::AuthSwitchRequest
            assert(firstByte == 0xFE);
        }
        virtual  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& s) const
        {
            s << "AuthSwitchRequest: "
              << "pluginName(" << pluginName << ") "
              << "pluginData(";
            for (auto c: pluginData)
            {
                s << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(c) << " ";
            }
            s << ") " << std::dec;
            return s;
        }
};

    }
}

#endif
```