# Linux/Mac hashing SHA-1

Tags: c++, c++11, cryptography, wrapper, openssl

To do password exchange on the SQL server I need to use SHA-1 to generate a hash (no plain password exchange).

This is done differently on Linux/Mac so I abstracted it slightly.

### ThorCryptWrapper.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_THOR_CRYPTO_WRAPPER_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_DETAILS_THOR_CRYPTO_WRAPPER_H

#ifdef  __APPLE__
#define COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#define THOR_SHA1(data, len, dst)   CC_SHA1(data, len, dst)
#else
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#define THOR_SHA1(data, len, dst)   SHA1(data, len, dst)
#endif

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace MySQL
    {

typedef unsigned char           ThorSHADigestStore[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

inline void thorSHA1(ThorSHADigestStore& dest, ThorSHADigestStore& src)
{
    THOR_SHA1(src, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, dest);
}

inline void thorSHA1(ThorSHADigestStore& dest, std::string const& src)
{
    THOR_SHA1(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&src[0]), src.length(), dest);
}

    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: Is there a *really* good reason you're writing code to use SHA-1? You do realize that collision attacks have been known for quite a while, and actually implemented to produce real collisions, right? This doesn't *directly* affect use for password hashing (AFAIK, no preimage attack has been published) but still points to a hash that's seriously compromised. If at all possible, I'd advise switching to something newer (e.g., SHA-256 or SHA-3).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: This is just implementing the MySQL "mysql_native_password" handshake requirements. They use SHA-1 as there specification.  `SHA1( password ) XOR SHA1( "20-bytes random data from server" <concat> SHA1( SHA1( password ) ) )`.  Documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/secure-password-authentication.html#packet-Authentication::Native41 You can see my use of it here: [ThorsSQL Lib: Part 3: Layer 5 HandShake](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158215/507)

Comment: For what it's worth: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sha256-authentication-plugin.html

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I know that's why in my code review I include: `Currently this client does not support that and will throw an exception (A fun task for somebody that want to try :-) )`

Answer (score 2):

There's not a huge amount to review here.

---

It looks like the Apple code is intended to be a drop-in replacement for OpenSSL, so you could probably just rename to match, rather than creating a new name:

```
#ifdef  __APPLE__
#define COMMON_DIGEST_FOR_OPENSSL
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#define SHA1 CC_SHA1
#else
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#endif
```

Whichever approach you take, don't forget to `#undef` the macro when you've finished using it (definitely before the end of the header), to avoid polluting the macro namespace for others.

---

I would prefer `src.data()` to `&src[0]` as the idiomatic way to access a string's characters as an array of `char`.

And I think I prefer `sizeof src` to `SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH` in the first overload, so that the connection is clear.

Is there any reason that `src` can't be a reference to `const` in both versions?

```
inline void thorSHA1(ThorSHADigestStore& dest, ThorSHADigestStore const& src)
{
    THOR_SHA1(src, sizeof src, dest);
}

inline void thorSHA1(ThorSHADigestStore& dest, std::string const& src)
{
    auto const src_bytes = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(src.data());
    THOR_SHA1(src_bytes, src.length(), dest);
}
```

---

I withhold comment on the suitability of SHA-1 for this purpose, as that appears to be something you're stuck with.